# Accessing ASP.NET Server variables in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

In Page_Load() function, I have populated an arraylist and a hashtable. I need to read their values in the $(document).ready(function(){...}.

I am a beginner in terms of ASP.NET and jQuery. Please suggest a way to do it.

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use PageMethods to make a call to your aspx page from  JS. [Here is a nice article](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) on how to  use page method with jQuery. You can return your "whatever" in your page method. If you want to serialize your server side objects before passing them to the client side, you can serialize them to JSON . [Here is an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx). You would just read your json data after your ajax call is successful(`"success: function(msg){//do something}"`) and update your HTML accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Page.ClientScript` property to register arrays, scripts etc.

For more information view [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a page.method in server side and call it in the client side script that return an array of values

```
by adding 

<scriptManager EnablePageMethods="true">

in the server side you create a function that return an array of values
ex:  GetArrayResult()


  if you intersting in this i will give you the rest of example
```

Comment: @peacmaker:you dont need EnablePageMethods="true" to call a page  method if you are using jQuery. see http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) will help you serialize the hashtable and array to JSON, and you can store these in a hidden field.  Then on the client side you can deserialize the strings to your javascript variables with:

```
var array = JSON.parse($('#hiddenTextField').val());
```